# Laravel: Consulta con Eloquent usando count

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

Quiero hacer una consulta que involucra un count, y funciona. La consulta es esta:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$id = $user->id;
$users = DB::table('cuentas as a')
        ->join('pasajeros as b', 'b.id', '=', 'a.pasajero_id')
        ->where('b.usuarios_id', $id)
        ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count'))
        ->get();
return $users;
```

El return $users me trae esto:

> [{"user_count":0}]

Y está bien, tengo 0, porque aún no hay ningún registro donde el id del usuario esté contenido. Pero lo que necesito hacer es que el contenido de $users sea únicamente el número, en ese caso, el 0.
Para así poder usarlo en un if, de lo contrario, ese $users no es un número cómo tal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El resultado es un objeto en un array, el cual entrega como resultado el método get() de Eloquent, por tal motivo debería poder accederse fácilmente de la siguiente manera

```
echo $users[0]->user_count;
```

De esta forma llamas al primer elemento del array (el cual es un objeto de users) y luego llamas su propiedad user_count.

---

También podrías usar el método `first()` para obtener el primer objeto directamente y no necesitar así llamar el primer elemento del array:

```
$users = DB::table('cuentas as a')
    ->join('pasajeros as b', 'b.id', '=', 'a.pasajero_id')
    ->where('b.usuarios_id', $id)
    ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count'))
    ->first();

echo $users->user_count;
```

Answer (score 1):

En laravel 5.2 puedes usar la funcion `withCount` a la cual le pasas la relacion como parametro.

```
$users = DB::table('cuentas as a')
    ->join('pasajeros as b', 'b.id', '=', 'a.pasajero_id')
    ->where('b.usuarios_id', $id)
    ->withCount('nombre_de_tu_relacion')
    ->first();
```

Luego lo llamas como $users->nombre_de_tu_relacion**_count.**

Para graficarlo mejor: Supongamos que quieres contar los usuarios, tal y como lo tienes en tu ejemplo, solamente debes usar `withCount('users')` (o como se llame tu relación) y luego llamarlo como `$users->users_count`. Bastante simple y entendible.

O en caso de que quieras seguir usando el codigo que tienes puedes "limpiarlo" un poquito mas usando `selectRaw`.

```
 $users = DB::table('cuentas as a')
    ->join('pasajeros as b', 'b.id', '=', 'a.pasajero_id')
    ->where('b.usuarios_id', $id)
    ->selectRaw('count(*) as user_count')
    ->first();
```

Saludos.

Comment: Buena información la proporcionada.

Comment: De momento sigo usando Laravel 4.2, me funciona todo bien. Gracias por tu aporte.