# Como contar los registros en laravel recibidos por request

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un buscador el cual busca las automotoras presentes por ciudad y me muestra en una vista el resultado en una tabla. En esa vista muestro un mensaje indicando el numero de registros que se logró encontrar dependiendo de la búsqueda realizada.

Dejo un **EJEMPLO** SIMILAR de como debería mostrar el numero de resultados.

```js
var RegionesYcomunas = {
  "regiones": [{
      "NombreRegion": "Area del Norte",
       "comunas": ["El Rosal", "El Cañon","Las Olas"]
  },
  {
      "NombreRegion": "Area Central",
      "comunas": ["El Bosque", "Los Valles", "La pradera verde"]
  },

  {
     "NombreRegion": "Area del Sur",
     "comunas": ["El Rio Nevado", "La Antartida", "Los Iceberg Frios"]
  }]
}


jQuery(document).ready(function () {

  var iRegion = 0;
  var htmlRegion = '<option value=" ">Seleccione una zona</option><option value=" " disabled="disabled">--</option>';
  var htmlComunas = '<option value=" ">Seleccione una ciudad</option><option value=" " disabled="disabled">--</option>';

  jQuery.each(RegionesYcomunas.regiones, function () {
    htmlRegion = htmlRegion + '<option value="' + RegionesYcomunas.regiones[iRegion].NombreRegion + '">' + RegionesYcomunas.regiones[iRegion].NombreRegion + '</option>';
                iRegion++;
});

            

  jQuery('#areas').html(htmlRegion);
  jQuery('#ciudades').html(htmlComunas);

  jQuery('#areas').change(function () {
      var iRegiones = 0;
      var valorRegion = jQuery(this).val();
      var htmlComuna = '<option value=" ">Seleccione una ciudad</option><option value=" " disabled="disabled">--</option>';
      jQuery.each(RegionesYcomunas.regiones, function () {
        if (RegionesYcomunas.regiones[iRegiones].NombreRegion == valorRegion){
          var iComunas = 0;
      jQuery.each(RegionesYcomunas.regiones[iRegiones].comunas, function(){
          htmlComuna = htmlComuna + '<option value="' + RegionesYcomunas.regiones[iRegiones].comunas[iComunas] + '">' + RegionesYcomunas.regiones[iRegiones].comunas[iComunas] + '</option>';
        iComunas++;
      });
    }
    iRegiones++;
  });
 
  jQuery('#ciudades').html(htmlComuna);
});


jQuery('#ciudades').change(function () {
  if(jQuery(this).val() == ' '){
                    
    $('#areas').focus();
    alert("Seleccione una zona primero.");
    return false;
  }
});

  jQuery('#areas').change(function () {
    if($('#areas').val() == ' '){
      
      $('#col_1').show();
      $('#col_2').show();
      $('#col_3').show();
      $('#col_4').show();
      $('#col_5').show();
      $('#col_6').show();  
      $('#col_7').hide();
      document.getElementById('result').style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById('result_2').style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById('result_3').style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById('hr').style.width = "1450%";
      document.getElementById('nothing').style.display = 'none';
    }
  });


  $(document).on('click', '.detalle', function(){
    if($('#areas').val() == ' '){
        $('#areas').focus();
        alert('Debe seleccionar una zona y luego una ciudad.');
        return false;
    }
    
    if($('#areas').val() == 'Area del Norte' && $('#ciudades').val() == 'El Rosal'){        
        
      $('#col_2').show();
      document.getElementById('hr').style.width = "1280%";
      $('#col_3').hide();
      $('#col_4').show();
      $('#col_5').hide();
      $('#col_1').show();
      $('#col_6').hide();
      document.getElementById('result').style.display = "inline-block";
      document.getElementById('result_2').style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById('result_3').style.display = "none";       document.getElementById('nothing').style.display = 'none';
      
    }else if($('#areas').val() == 'Area Central' && $('#ciudades').val() == 'El Bosque'){
      
      $('#col_1').hide();
      $('#col_5').show();
      $('#col_3').show();
      $('#col_4').hide();
      $('#col_2').hide();
      $('#col_6').hide();
      document.getElementById('result_2').style.display = 'inline-block';
      document.getElementById('result').style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById('result_3').style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById('hr').style.width = "1150%";
      document.getElementById('nothing').style.display = 'none';
      
    }else if($('#areas').val() == 'Area del Sur' && $('#ciudades').val() == 'La Antartida'){
      
      $('#col_2').hide();
      $('#col_4').hide();
      $('#col_5').hide();
      $('#col_1').hide();
      $('#col_3').hide();
      $('#col_6').show();
      document.getElementById('result_3').style.display = 'inline-block';
      document.getElementById('result').style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById('result_2').style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById('hr').style.width = "1200%";
      document.getElementById('nothing').style.display = 'none';
      
    }else if($('#areas').val() != '' && $('#ciudades').val() != ''){
      $('#col_1').hide();
      $('#col_2').hide();
      $('#col_3').hide();
      $('#col_4').hide();
      $('#col_5').hide();
      $('#col_6').hide();
      document.getElementById('nothing').style.display = "inline-block";
      document.getElementById('result_3').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('result').style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById('result_2').style.display = "none";
       document.getElementById('hr').style.width = "1000%";
   }
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 12pt;
}
table{
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.hide{
  display: none;
}
hr{
  width: 1450%;
  border-color: black;
}
select{
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 12pt;
  width: 38%;
  outline-style: none;
}
select:focus{
  border-color: red;
}
input{
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline-style: none;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: black;
  width: 20%;
  height: 8mm;
  font-size: 12pt;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
input:hover{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  color: white;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
input:active{
  transform: scale(0.9);
  transition-duration: 0.1s;
  
  -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.0/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
  <br>

   <select id="areas"></select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <select id="ciudades"></select>
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" id="submit" value="BUSCAR" class="detalle">

  <br><br>
  <label class="hide" id="nothing">Sin resultados para su búsqueda.</label>
  <label class="hide" id="result">Resultados encontrados para su búsqueda: 3.</label>
  <label class="hide" id="result_2">Resultados encontrados para su búsqueda: 2.</label>
  <label class="hide" id="result_3">Resultados encontrados para su búsqueda: 1.</label>
  <br><br>
  
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>COMPAÑIA</th>
        <th>CIUDAD</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><hr id="hr"></td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr id="col_1"> 
        <td>1</td>
        <td>&nbsp;MERCEDEZ-BENZ&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;El Rosal&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
     
      <tr id="col_2"> 
        <td>2</td>
        <td>&nbsp;CHEVROLET&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;El Rosal&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr id="col_3"> 
        <td>3</td>
        <td>&nbsp;CHEVROLET&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;El Bosque&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr id="col_4">
        <td>4</td>
        <td>&nbsp;BMW&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;El Rosal&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr id="col_5">
        <td>5</td>
        <td>&nbsp;Hyundai&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;El Bosque&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr id="col_6">
        <td>6</td>
        <td>&nbsp;Audi&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;La Antartida&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>
```

Lo que intento es mostrar del mismo modo que en el EJEMPLO el número de resultados de elementos, pero en LARAVEL con PHP. El cual tengo una vista con 2 `<select>` y un botón que me redirecciona a una vista diferente la cual me muestra los resultados.

Tengo de este modo el código del controlador:

```
public function BuscarPorCiudad(Request $request){

  $motors = CompaniaNew::all();
  $recibo = $request->ciudades;
  $contar = count([$request->all()]);

  try {
    foreach($motors as $motors){
      if ($motors->city == $request->ciudades){

        Session::flash('info', 'Se encontraron'.' '.$contar.' '.'registros en relación a su búsqueda.');
        return view('compañias-buscar')->with('compania', $motors)->with('recibo',$recibo);

      }
    }   
  } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
     // ESTA VEZ SE DEJARÁ EL CATCH VACÍO PORQUE NO MUESTRA EL ERROR 
     // QUE DEBE MOSTRAR PARA LOS CASOS QUE LA BÚSQUEDA NO COINCIDA
    }
    Session::flash('error', 'Lo sentimos. Su búsqueda no coincide con nuestros registros');
    return Redirect()->back();
}
```

El cual con `Session::flash()`; muestro el mensaje y es en donde quiero mostrar el numero de resultados, pero siempre me muestra 1. Cuando lo que busco es que cuente las filas mostradas según la búsqueda y ese sea el numero a mostrar.

Si el resultado contiene 2 filas en la tabla me deberia decir, se han encontrado 2 resultados para su búsqueda, por ejemplo.

Si son 3, debe mostrar un 3, si son más o menos el numero debe ir variando. Para ello use la variable `$contar`. Pero no me funciona.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que intentas contar?, ¿el número de campos que te llegan de tu objeto `$request` ó el número de filas de tu tabla `motors` que coinciden con la búsqueda?

Comment: Lo segundo amigo, el numero filas que coinciden con el resultado, como explique si el resultado muestra 5 filas, en el mensaje que muestro debería decir que se encontraron 5 resultados.

Comment: Otra pregunta mal planteada y que confunde a quienes responden.

Comment: Shaz. Estimado, ¿Usted cree de verdad que está mal, planteada la pregunta? y por ello no se entiende, suponiendo que soy otra persona quien lee esto y no conociera el problema, leo una pregunta así, entendería igual lo que busca lograr, quien realizó la pregunta.

Comment: @M4uriXD sí, no se ve en ninguna parte de la pregunta: 1. Resultado actual. 2. El código planteado y el ejemplo dista mucho del resultado esperado (según lo que leo en la pregunta). 3. ¿Hacer un buscador sin pasar por la base de datos? Revise su propia respuesta aceptada vs. la pregunta planteada y la respuesta de Bryro.

Comment: De hecho siempre pasa por la base de datos. Si no no podría obtener ningún resultado. Lo más seguro que no expliqué bien ese detalle,y lo tendré en consideración para futuras publicaciones (Explicar todo de una mejor manera). Y sobre el código entregado como lo mencioné en negrita, es solo un ejemplo ya que se me hacia algo dificil reproducir lo que quería lograr como resultado final si entregaba mi código en Laravel. Ese código realiza la misma tarea que mi código en laravel, solo con la diferencia que no consulta a la base de datos, pero con laravel si lo hago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondo a mi pregunta logré encontrar la solución a mi problema.

De este modo logro contar las filas segun la busqueda realizada.

```
public function BuscarPorCiudad(Request $request){

  $motors = CompaniaNew::all();
  $recibo = $request->ciudades;
  $contar = DB::table('compania')->where('compania.city', $recibo)
  ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as filas'))
  ->first();

  try {
    foreach($motors as $motors){
      if ($motors->city == $request->ciudades){

        Session::flash('info', 'Se encontraron'.' '.$contar->filas.' '.'registros en relación a su búsqueda.');
        return view('compañias-buscar')->with('compania', $motors)->with('recibo',$recibo);

      }
    }   
  } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
  // ESTA VEZ SE DEJARÁ EL CATCH VACÍO PORQUE NO MUESTRA EL ERROR 
  // QUE DEBE MOSTRAR PARA LOS CASOS QUE LA BÚSQUEDA NO COINCIDA
}
    Session::flash('error', 'Lo sentimos. Su búsqueda no coincide con nuestros registros');
    return Redirect()->back();
}
```

Lo que tenia mal en mi pregunta era la siguiente, linea:

```
$contar = count([$request->all()]);
```

El cual al comprobar que era lo que me traía el request->all() era el valor del select escogido, y al realizar lo siguiente:

```
$contar = DB::table('compania')->where('compania.city', $recibo)
   ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as filas'))
   ->first();
```

Se lograba especificar de mejor manera lo que se quiere contar. Esto ultimo lo obtuve de la siguiente fuente:

Fuente: [(enlace)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/16353/laravel-consulta-con-eloquent-usando-count)

Answer (score 2):

solo debes quitar los `[]`:

```
public function BuscarPorCiudad(Request $request){

  $motors = CompaniaNew::all();
  $recibo = $request->ciudades;
  $contar = count($request->all());

  try {
    foreach($motors as $motors){
      if ($motors->city == $request->ciudades){

        Session::flash('info', 'Se encontraron'.' '.$contar.' '.'registros en relación a su búsqueda.');
        return view('compañias-buscar')->with('compania', $motors)->with('recibo',$recibo);

      }
    }   
  } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
     // ESTA VEZ SE DEJARÁ EL CATCH VACÍO PORQUE NO MUESTRA EL ERROR 
     // QUE DEBE MOSTRAR PARA LOS CASOS QUE LA BÚSQUEDA NO COINCIDA
    }
    Session::flash('error', 'Lo sentimos. Su búsqueda no coincide con nuestros registros');
    return Redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: Funciona, pero es extraño el numero de registros que me dice que se encuentra, me aumenta en +1. Por ejemplo hice una prueba, y el resultado arrojó 3 registros y me dice que se encontraron 4. Lo puedo arreglar si le resto 1, pero ¿Porque sucede eso?

Comment: esto sucede por el token que se le pasa a laravel!

Comment: Acabo de realizar una 2da prueba y no toma para cuando el resultado es distinto, sigue mostrando siempre 4.

Comment: dale un var_dump($request->all()); y te daras cuenta que te estas enviando en realidad!

Comment: Ya veo, entiendo, pero mi idea era que contara las filas de la tabla que muestro en la vista. En cambio aquello me cuenta los valores recibidos por el request.